# Purpose of each disk access and why it may not occur

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I'm going over past papers for an exam I have and my university do not provide answers so that I can check them, please could you let me know if my understanding is correct and if not please could you correct it.

**Question:** A program P running on a Linux system takes the name and path of a file on disk containing text as an argument; it opens the file and reads the first character from it. Assuming the program is already running and the file exists, list the disk read requests that could occur, describing:

• The purpose of each disk access.

• Why the disk read request might not always occur.

**Attempt:** A disk read request might not always occur because a cache hit may occur and so the file can be read from cache without a disk read request. If this does not happen disk accesses will occur. One to get the file's name, another to get the path of the file and the final one to read the first character from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A disk read request might not always occur because a cache hit may occur and so the file can be read from cache without a disk read request.

Correct and complete.

> If this does not happen disk accesses will occur. One to get the file's name, another to get the path of the file and the final one to read the first character from the file

This one is far from complete and partially incorrect. In fact, there could be accesses for:

- The inode of the root directory in of the filesystem.
- At least one of the blocks that contain the list of files in the root directory.
- Repeat for each directory on the path to the file. (Plus symbolic link traversal if applicable.)
- The inode of the file.
- The first block of the file content.

Depending on the filesystem, each of these entries might involve one or more disk reads as the content could be spread across several blocks. Accessing a block of a file may require accessing a block where the list of blocks is contained, sometimes several levels deep.

In addition to these accesses, there may be disk accesses to load parts of the program code and data into RAM from swap. It isn't clear from the wording of the question whether it is assumed that the program is running *and the relevant bits are in RAM*. There could be other subtleties which I'm sure were not intended by the exam setter, such as a file that already exists on disk, but in an automounted directory that isn't currently mounted, which requires loading the driver for the filesystem before mounting.

Comment: Thank you for that...I agree the question is quite vague